# Listing out JSON data?

Tags: ajax, json, forms

How do i display the values that JSON returns?

```
function akaiphoneResponse(searchText){        
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: Drupal.settings.basePath + 'akaiphone/response',
        data: 'search_text=' + searchText,
        success: function(data) {
      $("#search-results", this).empty(); 
      var jsob = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
      $.each(data, function(i, item){
        content = item.link + "-" + item.title ;

          $(content).appendTo("#search-results");

      });
        }
    });
}
```

JSON:

```
{"matches":[{"title":"JUR 3420 Forretningsjus","link":"6451"}]}
```

atm title is always gives "undefined", and link turns out "function link() {[native code]}"
im a total noob at ajax and javascript, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as a replacement of your each function:

```
$.each(jsob.matches, function(i, item){
    content = item.link + "-" + item.title ;
    $(content).appendTo("#search-results");
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kGnJ2/

Comment: @Thor check the JSFiddle link I just added.. where is that error coming up?

Comment: it was on the last line, but i still had data in the code: $.each(DATA.matches, function(i, item), i changed it to jsob now and got a different error: jsob is null

Comment: @Thor in your question, there is this line right before the each function: var jsob = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);

Comment: sweet, works now, but only returns 1 search result, must be my php